# Prashal verbs, same meaning

Tags: phrasal-verbs

1 complete with the same meaning
Do you have a good relationship with your neighbours? (Well)
Do you ... your neighbours?

I don’t know where to find a list with all the prashal verbs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know either. But I think you should use "get on well with sb." to fill in the gap in your sentence:

> Do you **get on well with** your neighbors?

Note that you can also say "get on" or "get along (well)" with somebody to mean the same thing:

> I **get along well** with most of my colleagues.
>
> I don't **get on with** my sister.